# How safe is it to use prototypes Form.serialize()?

Tags: javascript, forms, serialization, prototypejs

Somehow, when using Prototype's `Form.serialize()` to submit complex forms, I always feel a bit unsure as to whether this will work in all cases.

Possible issues I worry about are quote/string escaping issues, or perhaps the submission of unusual character codes, anything that could mess up the process.

So the question is:

Is it safe (on the client side) to collect all the data from a form using Prototype and then send it to the server via AJAX or are there any browsers that are known to have troubles sending forms this way — or perhaps, lack of support for it?

Comment: If anyone could explain to me why my question is being downvoted it would help me understand what is so wrong about it. I could then avoid asking questions in the future, that do not suit the community. Thank You.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your question isn't very clear. I don't know what you are asking at this point.

Comment: I understand. I will try to improve it.

Comment: So long as the `form` mark up is well-formed (pun intended!), there should be no problems.

Comment: You seem to be asking if any version of a form serializer could have any issue in any browser. I'm going to go out on a limb, and say "yes" it's possible that there could be some issue somewhere.

Comment: Good point. I will make it more specific then.

Comment: I'm not certain why you would think there is an issue. When you use a Form library you are just simulating what the browser is already doing (meaning getting all the elements and sending name-value pairs to a destination). You need to list your specific concerns as to what you think could go wrong.

Comment: I thought so, too, but then i wondered if the browsers (internally) really use javascript to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While no browser that I know internally uses Javascript to submit a form, the **exact** details of how a form should be submitted are very well documented.

It is quite possible to write form submission code in Javascript that follows the protocol exactly.  On the other hand, an experienced coder may miss some of the edge cases -- like disabled checkbox controls.

I can't speak for the `prototype` library since I've never used it, but if there is a form that does not submit properly, or a server that does not take a submitted form, then it should be submitted as a bug report.

Comment: All the answers make sense and are informative. I picked yours because you provided another example for a possible issue (disabled checkbox controls) and you solved the case by making it clear that during the many years of active-usage testing that is going on with Prototype, a bug like that would have shown up by now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you were downvoted originally, it's a valid question.

I think that the real answer, though, is that the security aspect really happens on the backend. It's OK to serialize an entire form and send it through a request but you need to validate the information that you receive on the other side.

For instance, you don't want to do this (or the equivalent in another language):
(assume `$form` is the serialized form)

```
foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
  $object->$key = $value;
}

save($object);
```

Comment: Thank You for the input. Initially my question was aimed at any library and also it was a series of questions instead of a specific one.